# How to make EditText shows like Instagram after soft keyboard comes out?

Tags: android, android-edittext, instagram

How to make EditText shows like Instagram after soft keyboard comes out when I click the EditText?It just like being pushed up.Not like `google+` or other apps,these are like appearping after disappearing.

I tried `"windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` ,and if the EditText is not having background it's good.But if the EditText has some background,the soft keyboard will cover some part of the editText.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hide keyboard 
Try this..

```
this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

Comment: In fact the effect I want to achieve is let the edittext comes out above the soft keyboard without sparking when the keyboard appear.Not hide.Thank you

Comment: <activity android:name=".TodoEdit"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">

Comment: try this in manifest file.check that it will be solve your problem or not

Comment: I tried "windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" or "adjustResize" ,and it also doesn't take effect if edittext use background.

Comment: remove background and check that it will be run or not

Comment: If the item doesn't have background ,"windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" take effects.But no matter what background I tried,it has the simlar problem

Comment: But if not, the item which above the edittext will be covered by keyboard

Comment: you use scrolllview in layout in the parent of layout.

Comment: use this...<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    ...

    <!-- Your current layout here -->

</ScrollView>

Comment: I tried this one.But this like google+ not like instream.The edittextview will spark.It appears a short time after the keyboard showing.And I want both shows at the same time

Comment: No problem it take time to keyboard showing because these are the different views that is not your problem.

Comment: But I want to achieve the effect of Instream.It has a better user experience than sparking.And in fact it could come true

Comment: No it is not your problem two different view edittext and keyboard.

Comment: But then I wonder how Instream come true.The view which I use someting like its advise view

Comment: I dont understand what is instream.

Comment: Oh,very sorry.Instagram.I make a mistake.Instagram app